# SQL Server: list of views referencing other views

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server: I would like to produce a list of views that reference other views.
The reason for this so that views can be created int the proper sequence, not having to resort to obscure view names to accomplish this.
Oracle provides this solution:
select * from USER_DEPENDENCIES
where type = 'VIEW'
and referenced_type = 'VIEW'
Which produces the desired result.
I have not found anything similar in SQL Server; I have been referencing INFORMATION_SCHEMA and its various components without success.

Comment: The function `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` returns that information if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 1):

Here's a DMV query to get you started.

```
use tempdb
drop table if exists t

go
create table t(id int, a int, b int)
go
create or alter view v1 as select id, a from t
go
create or alter view v2 as select * from v1
go

select schema_name(v.schema_id) view_schema_name, v.name view_name, d.referenced_entity_name 
from 
sys.views v
join sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
  on v.object_id = d.referencing_id
```

which outputs

```
  view_schema_name      view_name      referenced_entity_name
--------------------- -------------- ---------------------------
dbo                   v1                 t
dbo                   v2                 v1
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sp_depends.

```
sp_depends 'YourViewNameHere'
```

You will get 2 recordsets. The first shows the objects that the view depends on, and the second shows the objects that depend on the view.